# c#.net website - How to let user choose a folder?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I basically want to open a dialog box on the click of a button..The user will choose a destination folder and then a text file will be created in the chosen Folder using the path in the dialogue box.

I have used asp.net's FileUpload to  upload files but I don't know how to chose a folder using it. Or there's some other way to do this? please help . Thanks.

Comment: Where do you want to achieve? Do you want to browse the user's file system for a download location or the server file's system for an upload location?

Comment: What I am trying to do is that fetch data from my database's table. Add that data to a .txt file and save it in a temporary folder. Then I need to let user chose the desired folder location and then copy this file in that folder that is chosen by user.

Comment: I just need the path somehow.

Answer (score 2):

The only way you can be writing to a folder on the user computer is by having the user click on a button and then your server would send the file and the user will be prompted for where he wants to save it:

```
public void BtnDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=foo.txt");
    Response.Write("some text contents that will be sent to the user");
}
```

Now simply place this download button somewhere on the page:

```
<asp:LinkButton 
    ID="BtnDownload" 
    runat="server"
    OnClick="BtnDownload_Click" 
    Text="Download file" 
/>
```

The `FilUpload` control you are mentioning in your question is used for the client to upload files to the server, not to download.

Answer (score 1):

The browser won't normally let you access the users drive directly. It's a security issue. So as was said earlier, you normally just send the file to the users browser and they/it decide where to save it etc.

What you're trying to do could probably be done using java or silverlight, etc. I doubt you want to have to go there though.

Is there some reason you can't just send the file to them and let them / their browser decide how to save it just like is normally done with file downloads?